# What's with the music in the TV series "Stalker?"

Tags: production, soundtrack, stalker

The end of each episode of the TV series ["Stalker"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalker_(TV_series)) usually has a song playing in the background.  So far, I've been able to recognize each of the songs as a cover version of some well known song that was popular when it was new.

It takes considerable effort to recognize the songs. I can understand using cover versions - they are probably cheaper to license than the originals.  That's fine.  They seemed to be from one particular group, so I thought maybe there was a decision to always use that one band.  But after searching a bit, I [found that the songs at the end of each episode](http://filmmusicreporter.com/2014/09/26/john-frizzell-scoring-cbs-drama-stalker/) are from varying artists.

**I would like to know if there was an interview or anything that explains why cover versions in that particular style were chosen.**

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because these kind of covers [fit the format of the show](https://nerdgeist.com/2014/12/06/a-salute-to-the-music-department-of-stalker/):

> The right music can take a scene from good to
>   great, making it more exciting, heartbreaking or unnerving. Music can
>   have a real emotional impact on the audience, as it has clearly done
>   with *Stalker*.
>
> *Stalker* is a show full of suspense, cue lots of tension building and
>   chilling music throughout the episodes. **However what really makes
>   Stalker stand out is the songs played at the end of each episode.**
>
> At the end of the pilot we saw the main antagonist of the series
>   standing outside the main protagonist’s house watching her. The song
>   ‘Creep’, covered by Michelle Branch, began to play, so perfectly
>   describing the character and hinting at how this ongoing storyline
>   would unfold. **It was so fitting; it sent shivers down my spine.** It was
>   the perfect way to end the first episode.
>
> But it didn’t just end with the pilot. Instead it was decided that
>   these haunting songs would conclude every episode. Hailed as the
>   anthems of *Stalker*, these songs have become a staple of the show.
>   **Every song is a cover, arranged in such a way to keep up the sinister
>   and scary vibe of the show right until the credits roll. The lyrics of
>   each song are also a great match to the show’s title, usually alluding
>   to some creepy or obsessive behaviour.** Each song fits not only to the
>   show but also to the episode that it goes with.
>
> *Stalker* has actually made me see these songs in a different light.
>   Tunes like ‘One Way Or Another’ and ‘I Want You To Want Me’ have
>   always seemed like fun classic 80’s hits but when broken down into a
>   softer melody as in *Stalker* a much darker tone is suggested.

Comment: That's actually the problem.  Those covers are one of the reasons I **didn't** like the show.  Most of them are like listening to a 45 rpm record played at 33 or 18 rpm.  Slowed, draggy, low pitched, nearly unrecognizable. They took the closing scenes from closure fir the story to "OMG, where's the remote.  Change the channel before they butcher another song." They didn't improve the scenes, they made them unbearable.

Comment: And, the link is to a fan post, not a statement from the makers.

Comment: @JRE personally, I loved the show and the music. I think the point here is spot on. A seemingly innocuous song, when presented differently, can make you reassess the lyrics and make them sound, well, stalkerish.